# retrieving data into a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file that has:

```
1 2 3 4 0 5 6 7 8
```

How do I show the data in a 2D array of size [3,3]?

I'm new to C# and any help would be great!

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
int[,] result = new int[3, 3];
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
{
    j = 0;
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        result[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work`?

Comment: You might want to pass StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries as a second parameter to Split() method.

Comment: In your example it looks like the file contains 9 numbers in one single row, but your code assumes the file to contains 3 rows with three numbers each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your 9 numbers are on the same line, then splitting by new line will not help. You can do:

```
foreach (var num in input.Split(' '))
{
    result[i / 3, i % 3] = int.Parse(num.Trim());
    i++;
}
```

because:

```
i    i / 3 (div)    i % 3 (mod)
0    0              0
1    0              1
2    0              2
3    1              0
4    1              1
5    1              2
6    2              0
7    2              1
8    2              2
```

Answer (score 2):

divide by 3 and convert to integer to get row, use modulo 3 to get col.

```
 j=0;
 foreach (var col in input.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        result[j/3, j%3] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
        j++;
    }
```